# How to specify a typed variable when you don't know the type

Tags: c#, oop, generics

I have this extension method for my BusinessObject class:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T Clone<T>(this T obj)
        where T: BusinessObject<T>, new()
    {
        T newObj = new T();
        var props = newObj.Properties;

        foreach (var p in props)
            newObj.Properties[p.Name].SetValue(newObj, obj.Properties[p.Name].GetValue(obj));

        return newObj;
    }
}
```

The contents of that method work great, but I have a non-generic BusinessObject class and a generic counterpart.  A lot of my code passes around an instance of a generic version of the object inside a non-generic variable (please don't ask me 20 questions about why).  I haven't had a problem until now because when I call this extension method it expects a generic version.

The code that calls the Clone method uses a BusinessObject variable that contains an instance of a BusinessObject variable.  How can I cast the variable to what it actually is?  In other words:

```
Customer cust = new Customer();   // Customer derives from BusinessObject<Customer>
var CustomerClone = cust.Clone(); // This works

BusinessObject obj = cust;
var clone = obj.Clone(); // This doesn't work
```

Now of course in this example I know that 'obj' is a Customer, but in my actual method I don't know that as it could be any number of derived types.  I can find out what the derived type is easily enough by simply using GetType(), but how do I cast the variable to that type at runtime?

Comment: Anything preventing you from using `MemberwiseClone` ?

Comment: @leppie 'var props = newObj.Properties' is grabbing the properties that need to be cloned.  Properties is a BusinessObjectProperties variable, which is a class I created to hold the PropertyInfo along with some other meta info for properties.  Not everything is getting copied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I would say "lose the `T`" - you aren't using for anything important that can't be done in other  ways (`Activator.CreateInstance`, for example). You could offer two APIs - one generic, one non-generic, to allow for convenient casting. For example:

```
BusinessObject newObj = (BusinessObject)Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());
```

It is also quite key because the `T` you want is not actually the **declaration** `T`, but the **concrete** `T`. Meaning: if you have a `SuperCustomer : Customer`, but place it in a `Customer` variable, and then call `Clone`, you want to get a new `SuperCustomer`. `T`, however, would be `Customer`. Using `GetType()` would be far more reliable.

Another useful trick here is `dynamic`, which is a sneaky way of flipping from non-generic to generic. Consider:

```
dynamic foo = 123;
Bar(foo);

void Bar<T>(T bar) {
   Console.WriteLine(typeof(T));
}
```

will write `System.Int32`. It has flipped to the correct `T` on the fly, despite only really knowing about `object` at the compiler (`dynamic` is implemented mostly as `object`, with some fancy bits).

However, to emphasise - I wouldn't use that here: I would just have:

```
public static BusinessObject Clone(this BusinessObject obj)
{
    BusinessObject newObj = (BusinessObject)
          Activator.CreateInstance(obj.GetType());
    var props = newObj.Properties;

    foreach (var p in props)
        newObj.Properties[p.Name].SetValue(newObj,
          obj.Properties[p.Name].GetValue(obj));

    return newObj;
}
```

with `dynamic` as my fallback strategy if I really needed the generics.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying that but it wasn't working right (but it compiled).  It was calling Properties on the non-generic version when I needed it to call it on the generic version, but I think I just need to use GetType() and reflection to get at the right method like you say.

Comment: And thanks for the dynamic tip, even though in this case the code may have to be ported to 2008 for one project so prolly gonna try to avoid that for now.

Comment: @Brandon if Properties is returning someting different depending on the generic vc non-generic API, then that is a bug IMO; you should make that polymorphic (`virtual`) so that it returns the same thing

Comment: yeah I'm struggling with that too... it is virtual but it gets set by a method in the generic version.  (And I would mark the non-generic version as abstract but then I can't use the extension method on it).  But if a variable is declared as a 'Foo' then isn't it going to return properties from 'Foo' even if it contains a more derived object with overriden virtual properties?  Or am I getting mixed up on that point?

Comment: Okay, I've been trying to figure out what you had in mind for the last code section of your answer... did you mean to have T as the return type?  And if so did you forget to make it a generic method?  I'm confused...

Comment: @BrandonMoore sorry, typo - fixing